# iCloud Music Library and Music Playing Apps: How?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, itunes, mpmediaitem

Music playing Apps are have been at a disadvantage when compared with the built-in Music app because it has not been possible to get an asset url for tracks in a device's library unless they have been explicitly synced to the device.

Recently, my own iPhone decided to keep all my music in the "iCloud Music Library", and, therefore, my own App was unable to see my music!

I am getting the impression that Apple wants to move to HTTP Live Streaming, and I suspect that this may be the way I should access tracks that are in iCloud Music Storage. Does anyone know if this is right? Alternatively, how do I access iCloud Music Storage items from my App?

Answer (score 1):

You NEED to use the `systemMusicPlayer` if you want to playback Apple Music content.

From you answer to Ben it seems like you are not.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this property: [`MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem).

If you need these items to be playable, they should be downloaded when you request them to be played with `[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer]`, but there's no API as far as I know to trigger this behavior without playing the song (or to monitor the download status).

Comment: I want to avoid using MPMusicPlayerController. I have my own specialized UI. I already use MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem in my App so that users can see which items need to be downloaded. Trouble is that in the latest version of Apple's Music App, the download icon does not seem to activate the MPMediaItem.location property- I was forced to use iTunes Syncing.